# Dialogflow CX - Form Parameter FINAL and UPDATED Event Not working

Tags: dialogflow-cx

The DialogFlow CX with Page Form Parameters was working well in the test simulator and recently, my chat bots are not responding after user inputs.

When i tried to troubleshoot the issue i realized that the $page.params.status='FINAL' or the $page.params.someparameter.status='UPDATED' events are not firing properly. Due to this the routes are getting failed.

Initially i thought the issue is in my Project. Then i tried the prebuilt agent (travel-baggage claim) in another project. Even that behaves the same without any response after the user inputs are collected.

I also reported this issue to the Developer Advocates in Twitter and updating here as well to get some response from the community.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I’ve tried to replicate your use case but I was able to successfully trigger the condition routes `$page.params.status = "FINAL"` and `$page.params.parameter-name.status = "UPDATED"` as expected and transition to the defined page from my end.

See the following for reference:

1. `$page.params.status = "FINAL"`
   [image: Image 1]
2. `$page.params.parameter-name.status = "UPDATED"`
   [image: Image 2]

To troubleshoot the issue, you may check if all the conditions defined in your condition route are fulfilled. Also, you may need to check if the condition rules applied is **OR** or **AND**. If **AND**, make sure that all conditions are fulfilled in order to transition to the defined page or flow.

As for the prebuilt agent ***Travel: baggage claim***, I was also able to replicate the same behavior. However, I noticed that this is a different issue since the issue is caused by the webhook being unable to provide a response and not caused by triggering the condition route. I was able to verify this by adding a static response on the condition route and by checking the logs from the simulator. See screenshots below for more information.

1. Static response
   [image: Image 3]
2. Log snippet from simulator
   [image: Image 4]

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying the Issue on webhook failure. This happens not just in pre-built agents even in the project which i built 3 months back. This was working well suddenly the calls are not invoked. I suspected the events are not fired.

Is this something Google look into right ?

Comment: As seen above, the conditions $page.params.status = “FINAL” and $page.params.parameter-name.status = “UPDATED” are triggered expectedly for both sample use case and prebuilt agent. You may check if there are any changes in your agent recently that may have affected this behavior. If the issue still persists, I advise you to open a [Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/getting-support#gcp-support) case or to report your issue on [Dialogflow CX Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/getting-support#issues).

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a new flow and migrated all the pages and it works well. I suspect the flow got corrupted when i programmatically tried to update via API.